# Using factory girl, Rspec2 and Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, factory-bot

Currently I'm trying to integrate factory girl for my testing framework. I was successfully  able to integrate factory girl with my rails 3.1.0 app and its working fine.

I'm using

- rspec2
- factory girl
- rails 3.1.0

Following are the references I had

http://www.pmamediagroup.com/2009/04/tutorial-install-rspec-rails-factory-girl/

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki

http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/master

http://www.deploymentzone.com/2011/05/19/factory_girl-rspec-2-and-rails-3/

http://www.codethinked.com/rails-3-baby-steps-part-3

And i could write some test cases like

```
it "user should valid with name" do
    user = Factory.build(:with_name)
    user.should be_valid
end
```

So as I can see there are commands like `'should be_valid'`, My question is , is there any place I can get all the commands in one place, so that I can see what are the commands I can use, like `should be_valid`.

I have gone through the factorygirl documentation, but couldn't find any place like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations

That .should-style comparison sugar is part of the rspec-expectations gem.
Notice you can write custom expectation matchers as well. =)

Comment: You bet! Diving into TDD with rails is quite a rewarding process. Have fun. =)